# Multi-dimensional dimension type

Tags: c++, c++17

## Introduction

When implementing a one-dimensional array, you need to keep track of the size.  Such quantities are best represented by `std::size_t`:

```
std::size_t count;
```

Analogously, when implementing a multi-dimensional array, you need to store the dimensions.  This time, a one-dimensional `std::size_t` does not suffice.  You need multiple dimensions.  Of course, something like this suffices:

```
std::array<std::size_t, N> dims;
```

but in my opinion, it makes more sense to use a dedicated type.  As such, I implemented a multi-dimensional dimension type in C++17, so that you can use:

```
Dimensions<N> dims;
```

A common operation is to convert from multiple indices to one flat index.  For example, given a 3 × 4 2-dimensional array indexed by 2-dimensional indices:

```
+--------+--------+--------+
| (0, 0) | (0, 1) | (0, 2) |
+--------+--------+--------+
| (1, 0) | (1, 1) | (1, 2) |
+--------+--------+--------+
| (2, 0) | (2, 1) | (2, 2) |
+--------+--------+--------+
| (3, 0) | (3, 1) | (3, 2) |
+--------+--------+--------+
```

The corresponding flat indices look like:

```
+----+----+----+
|  0 |  1 |  2 |
+----+----+----+
|  3 |  4 |  5 |
+----+----+----+
|  6 |  7 |  8 |
+----+----+----+
|  9 | 10 | 11 |
+----+----+----+
```

This operation is the core part.  The `at` member function is provided, and `operator()` is also supported for convenience:

```
Dimensions<2> dims{4, 3};

dims(1, 2)                 // returns 5
dims.at({1, 2})            // returns 5
```

The practice in the standard library is that `operator[]` (in this case, `operator()`) does no error checking, whereas `at` throws an exception on out-of-range input.  However, my principle is that error checking should be an opt-out feature instead of opt-in.  As such, *both `operator()` and `at` do error checking by default.*  It is even possible to do it manually:

```
dims.valid({1, 2})         // returns true
dims.valid({4, 2})         // returns false
```

That said, sometimes it is truly unnecessary, and I decided to trust the user in such cases.  It is also possible to disable error checking if you know what you are doing:

```
dims.at(unchecked, {1, 2}) // returns 5, no error checking
```

This way, you don't accidentally bypass the check, but can do intentionally.  Here, `unchecked` is an object used to disambiguate, similar to `std::allocator_arg`, `std::in_place`, etc.

## Code

Here's the header `dimension.hpp`:

```
/**
 * @file dimension.hpp
 * Implements multi-dimensional utilities.
 */

#ifndef INC_DIMENSION_HPP_CAdUgZHijL
#define INC_DIMENSION_HPP_CAdUgZHijL

#include <array>
#include <cstddef>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <type_traits>

/**
 * L. F.'s library
 */
namespace LF_lib {

/**
 * Multi-dimensional utilities.
 */
namespace multi {

  /**
   * Tag type to indicate unchecked versions of functions.
   */
  struct unchecked_t {
    explicit unchecked_t() = default;
  };

  /**
   * Tag object to indicate unchecked versions of functions.
   */
  inline constexpr unchecked_t unchecked{};

  /**
   * Encapsulates @c N dimensions.
   * Aggregate type that only contains one public member of type <tt>std::array<std::size_t, N></tt>.
   * @c N can be zero.
   *
   * @tparam N The number of dimensions
   */
  template <std::size_t N>
  struct Dimension {
    using dimension_t = std::array<std::size_t, N>; ///< Type for dimensions.
    using     index_t = std::array<std::size_t, N>; ///< Type for indices.

    dimension_t dimensions; ///< Stores the @c N dimensions.

    /**
     * @name Observers
     * @{
     */

    /**
     * Returns the number of dimensions.
     *
     * @return @c N
     */
    static constexpr std::size_t order() noexcept { return N; }

    /**
     * Returns the total size.
     *
     * @return The product of all dimensions
     */
    constexpr std::size_t size() const noexcept
    {
      std::size_t res = 1;
      for (std::size_t dim : dimensions)
        res *= dim;
      return res;
    }

    /**
     * @}
     */

    /**
     * @name Element access
     * @{
     */

    /**
     * Checks whether the given indices are in range.
     *
     * @param indices The indices
     *
     * @return @c true if <tt>indices[i] < dimensions[i]</tt> for <tt>i = 0, 1, 2, ..., N-1</tt>, @c false otherwise
     */
    constexpr bool valid(const index_t& indices) const noexcept
    {
      for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        if (indices[i] >= dimensions[i])
          return false;
      return true;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the flat index of the element at @c indices.
     *
     * @param indices The indices
     *
     * @pre   <tt>valid(indices)</tt>
     * @throw std::out_of_range At least one index is out of range
     *
     * @return <tt>(...((indices[0] * dimensions[1] + indices[1]) * dimensions[2] + indices[2]) * ...) * dimensions[N-1] + indices[N-1]</tt>
     */
    constexpr std::size_t at(const index_t& indices) const
    {
      if (!valid(indices))
        throw std::out_of_range{"LF_lib::multi::Dimension<N>::at "
                                "indices out of range"};
      return at(unchecked, indices);
    }

    /**
     * Unchecked version of @c at.
     */
    constexpr std::size_t at(unchecked_t, const index_t& indices) const noexcept
    {
      std::size_t res = 0;
      for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        res = res * dimensions[i] + indices[i];
      return res;
    }

    /**
     * Parentheses notation of @c at.
     * Let <tt>indices</tt> denote <tt>index_t{static_cast<std::size_t>(args)...}</tt>.
     *
     * @tparam Args The types of the indices
     * @param  args The indices
     *
     * @pre    <tt>sizeof...(Args) == N</tt>
     * @pre    <tt>std::conjunction_v<std::is_convertible<Args, std::size_t>...></tt>
     * @pre    <tt>valid(indices)</tt>
     * @return <tt>at(indices)</tt>
     * @throw std::out_of_range At least one index is out of range
     */
    template <typename... Args>
    constexpr std::size_t operator()(Args&&... args) const
    {
      static_assert(sizeof...(Args) == N,
                    "LF_lib::multi::Dimension<N>::operator() "
                    "must be called with N arguments");
      static_assert(std::conjunction_v<std::is_convertible<Args, std::size_t>...>,
                    "LF_lib::multi::Dimension<N>::operator() "
                    "must be called with arguments "
                    "implicitly convertible to std::size_t");

      index_t indices{static_cast<std::size_t>(args)...};
      if (!valid(indices))
        throw std::out_of_range{"LF_lib::multi::Dimension<N>::operator() "
                                "indices out of range"};
      return at(unchecked, indices);
    }

    /**
     * @}
     */
  };

  /**
   * Deduction guide.
   * Deduces <tt>Dimension<N></tt> for @c N arguments.
   */
  template <typename... Args>
  Dimension(Args...) -> Dimension<sizeof...(Args)>;

}

}

#endif
```

You can run Doxygen to generate the documentation.
Here's a test, which is also an example of how `Dimension` can be used:

```
#include "dimension.hpp"
#include <type_traits>

using namespace LF_lib::multi;

int main()
{
  {
    constexpr Dimension<5> dim {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    static_assert(dim.order() == 5);
    static_assert(dim.size() == 120);

    static_assert(!dim.valid({1, 1, 1, 1, 1}));
    static_assert(dim.at({0, 1, 2, 3, 4}) == 119);
    static_assert(dim.at({0, 1, 2, 3, 4}) == dim.at(unchecked, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}));
    // static_assert(dim.at({1, 1, 1, 1, 1}));

    static_assert(dim(0, 1, 2, 2, 4) == dim.at({0, 1, 2, 2, 4}));
  }
  {
    constexpr Dimension<0> dim = {};
    static_assert(dim.order() == 0);
    static_assert(dim.size() == 1);

    static_assert(dim.valid({}));
    static_assert(dim.at({}) == 0);
    static_assert(dim.at({}) == dim.at(unchecked, {}));

    static_assert(dim() == 0);
  }
  {
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<Dimension<5>, decltype(Dimension{1, 2, 3, 4, 5})>);
    // static_assert(std::is_same_v<Dimension<5>, decltype(Dimension(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))>);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<Dimension<0>, decltype(Dimension{})>);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<Dimension<0>, decltype(Dimension())>);
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks really nice!

Comment: This may just be a style nit or a copy and past error, but I believe that the second namespace, starting with `namespace multi {` should be another level of indentation.

Comment: On my machine with gcc 8.3.1, I get a compile error on the last line: `error: cannot deduce template arguments for ‘Dimension’ from ()`.  Which compiler are you using?

Comment: @Edward, [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/kORgLc) seems to be able to compile it. Perhaps there is a bug in gcc 8.3.1 with deduction guides? My intuition says that it should compile, but may be I am wrong, didn't thoroughly read standard.

Comment: @Edward I can compile it in Visual Studio 2017 when using the C++17 standard.

Comment: It also compiles cleanly with clang++ 7.0.1

Comment: Couldn't you use nested namespaces here?

Comment: @yuri How? I’m already using `LF_lib::multi` right?

Comment: Not for the declaration. E.g. `namespace LF_lib::multi {`. You are using C++17 so this should be possible or is there some other reason you omitted this?

Comment: @yuri I wanted to document namespaces separately.  Can I make Doxygen work with `namespace LF_lib::multi`?

Comment: I do not know but it explains why you didn't use it yet, thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lovely clean readable code - nice.  `:-)`

I don't agree with your bounds-checking philosophy (imposing either run-time overhead or syntactic clutter), but I'll respect your choice.  I find it, um, *interesting* that although we have bounds checking, we still cheerfully allow our accessors `at()` and `size()` to overflow the range of `std::size_t`.

Review points, in no particular order:

- It's great that you provide a deduction guide; it seems a waste not to use that for at least one of the `dim` variables in the demo program!

- I get a compilation failure for the use of `Dimension()` default constructor:

  ```
  220508.cpp:204:71: error: cannot deduce template arguments for ‘Dimension’ from ()
       static_assert(std::is_same_v<Dimension<0>, decltype(Dimension())>);
  ```

  I think this is just a consequence of using `struct` initialisation, rather than declaring a constructor.
- It's slightly frustrating that only the `()` accepts unpacked arguments, and we need to write `{`..`}` to construct an `index_t` when using `at()` or `valid()`.
- It's not necessary or particularly useful to mark a default constructor `explicit` - it can never be a conversion.

Comment: Great! Thank you! As to the second bullet, that's strange because I compiled it successfully. ([demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/mKixRnplzrepFw6t))

Comment: Also, as to `operator()`: it is considered to be "convenience syntax" so I removed the `{ }`. I used universal references because otherwise an object that is intended to be converted to `size_t` may be accidentally copied. For example, I may have an lvalue `foo` of non-copyable type `Foo`, and I want to make sure `dim(foo)` works. But it didn't really work out — I intended to use `std::forward<Args>(args)...` but seems I forgot it ...

Comment: I marked the default constructor `explicit` because I was imitating [\[allocator.tag\]](http://eel.is/c++draft/allocator.tag) ... But good point anyway! :)

Comment: Actually, I think you were probably right to use the operator forwarding - a cast isn't a call, so shouldn't cause an unnecessary copy.  I should withdraw that criticism!

Answer (score 3):

Writing it down here so I don't forget it: there is a bug in the code about perfect forwarding. I wrote

```
template <typename... Args>
constexpr std::size_t operator()(Args&&... args) const
{
    // ...
    index_t indices{static_cast<std::size_t>(args)...};
    // ...
}
```

when it should be

```
template <typename... Args>
constexpr std::size_t operator()(Args&&... args) const
{
    // ...
    index_t indices{static_cast<std::size_t>(std::forward<Args>(args))...};
    // ...
}
```

Also, it is preferable to constrain the function with SFINAE instead of putting in `static_assert`s:

```
template <typename... Args, typename = std::enable_if_t<
    sizeof...(Args) == N &&
    std::conjunction_v<std::is_convertible<Args, std::size_t>...>
>>
constexpr std::size_t operator()(Args&&... args) const;
```